# OnProgressUpdate cant SetText in TextView

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
protected Long doInBackground(String... address) {
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                setProgress(100);
                onProgressUpdate(getping(address[0]));
            }
        }    

protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values){
                result.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
                builder.setContentText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
                notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
            }
```

This chunk works fine on Android Oreo and above but fails to set text on any version below

**LOG CAT:-**

> 11-05 16:18:26.041 4720-4752/com.pcartistofficial.pingtesterforgames
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: com.pcartistofficial.pingtesterforgames, PID: 4720
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6357)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:909)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4690)
>           at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:11801)
>           at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11765)
>           at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11749)
>           at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6858)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4057)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3915)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3890)
>           at com.pcartistofficial.pingtesterforgames.MainActivity$BackgroundTasker.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:96)
>           at com.pcartistofficial.pingtesterforgames.MainActivity$BackgroundTasker.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:90)
>           at com.pcartistofficial.pingtesterforgames.MainActivity$BackgroundTasker.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: The error says "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views". It means you are trying to access a view from non-ui thread, probably in doInBackground method

Comment: @Emil but it works fine on Android Oreo +. With the same exact code.

Comment: Btw the issuing command is  onProgressUpdate(2) called from withen doInBackground() . How do i modify so it can work for versions before too

Comment: Its better to put ur doinbackground method code also.Because it shows the error in that method only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you call this method directly in doInBackground method cause this exception.
Instead, try to call publishProgress({your values}) in doInBackground method which calls onProgressUpdate method

[Reference to AsyncTask API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...))